# Restrict Armature only for Pose Mode

Tags: rigging, armature

Is there a way to restrict the mode of armature object only for pose mode? Because once you created bones on Edit Bone and finished tweaking setting on Object Mode, It's unnecessary to go into those other modes but Pose Mode And I sometimes accidentally go into Edit Bone mode by pressing Tab. So I wondered whether there is such an option just like disabling option to select the object on Outliner or Locking Location / Rotation / Scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this method will disable edit mode of the mesh too.

First put the armature layers into the [Protected layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/properties/skeleton.html#protected-layers).

> To do so, in the Skeleton panel, Ctrl-LMB click on the relevant
> button, the layer lock will be enabled.
>
> .. all bones in this layer will not be editable...for all proxies

Here is an example using  [Vincent](https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5718a967c379cf04929a4247), a free, open source, fully rigged, professional model.
[image]

Then save the file.
Then open a new file and <kbd>File</kbd>--><kbd>Link</kbd> --><kbd>select the .blend file</kbd>--> <kbd>Object folder</kbd> and select the object and its armature

After the object and armature are linked into the scene, select the armature with <kbd>RMB</kbd> and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to make it a [proxy object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html#proxy-objects)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaAHA5IQp_g&feature=youtu.be&t=3m16s

[image]
If you upload your [.blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  I can make an example

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer!
So basically what I need to do is, first protect bones and link armature and mesh to other blend file, Then I will not able to go to Edit Bone mode from the blend file.

Comment: And make the armature a proxy object so you can still go into pose mode to animate it.

Comment: I learned this after watching a documentary on how professionals organize their files. This method is very powerful because if the original file/mesh gets changed, all the other linked files get the updated meshes/textures automatically.  So the animator can simply focus on animating and the other stuff is automatic.

Comment: I see. Do you have some recommended web sites or tutorials that I can learn Animation by Blender in depth? Because comparing to mesh modeling or texturing, Animation is whole another science and need real professional instruction to do otherwise I will end up wasting my time for the things I can do it much more quickly if I knew the way.

Comment: The manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/index.html is a thorough introduction to the basic concepts. That is where I learned it. Youtube has great tutorials but they dont cover all the topics like the manual does. After you know all the buttons, then its all about getting good  with practice. https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig/57443403c379cf17984528fa